# Nested flex containers with inner scroll bar and snug/covering lower container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a nested structure of flexbox containers, where an inner container needs to show potentially large content in a scrollable pane. However, sometimes the content is small.

There's an additional container that needs to be always visible, and that I'd like to have just below the scrollable content, i.e. not far down at the bottom unless the scrollable pane content "pushes" it down - the viewport can be much larger than the content.

What I have right now does everything except have the "Right bottom" come up when the "Right top content" is small:

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u6dou3wf/10/

[image: JsFiddle output]

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px;
}

.right-top-wrapper {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background: blue;
}

.right-top-content {
  margin: 4px;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
  background: pink;
}

.right-bottom {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="left">
 Left content
 </div>
 <div class="right">
  <div class="right-top-wrapper">
   <div class="right-top-content">
    Right top content
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-bottom">
   Right bottom
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

How can I get the "Right bottom" to be snugly below the "Right top content", i.e. get the blue section to shrink if the pink section is small, and then grow to whatever size is available inside the green (minus yellow) if the pink section is large?

I have tried `.right-top-wrapper { flex: 0 1 0; }` but then it shrinks to nothing (a consequence of `overflow-y: scroll` or `auto`, which I have to have to allow large "Right top content").

Comment: This what you're going for? https://jsfiddle.net/u6dou3wf/11/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your blue container (`.right-top-wrapper`) is set to `flex: 1 1 0`. This breaks down to:

- `flex-grow: 1`
- `flex-shrink: 1`
- `flex-basis: 0`

It's the `flex-grow: 1` that's forcing the element to consume all available space in the column, leaving the content (pink box) behind, and pinning the yellow "Right bottom" box to the bottom.

*You wrote:*

> I have tried `.right-top-wrapper { flex: 0 1 0; }` but then it shrinks to nothing (a consequence of `overflow-y: scroll` or `auto`, which I have to have to allow large "Right top content").

No, it's a consequence of `flex-basis: 0`, which translates to `height: 0`. Without `flex-grow: 1` to expand the height like before, the box has a zero height.

Try this instead: `.right-top-wrapper { flex: 0 1 auto; }`

Now `flex-grow` is disabled and the box takes the height of the content.

You also need to release the fixed height on the pink box so it expands along with the blue container.

```
.right-top-content { 
     /* height: 100px */ 
     min-height: 100px; /* new */
}
```

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u6dou3wf/13/) (little content)

[**revised fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/u6dou3wf/14/) (lots of content)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, After having a quick fiddle, and if i am right in thinking of what you want to achieve, Change your CSS:

```
.main {
  display: flex;
  height: 200px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  background: red;
}
.right {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px;
}

.right-top-wrapper {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: blue;
}

.right-top-content {
  margin: 4px;
  flex: auto;
  background: pink;
}

.right-bottom {
  flex: 0 0 0;
  background: yellow;
  margin: 4px;
}
```

If you want the main to be a fixed width, adjust that accordingly too.